# Como suavizar aparecimento de divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

No evento `onload`do meu site, eu carrego uma função em que faz um gif de loading que estava aparecendo, suma para que o conteudo do site apareça.

```
<body onload="carregar()">
       <div id="preload">
             <img src="_imagens/loading.gif">
       </div>
       <div id="conteudo">
            //Aqui tem todo o site, cabeçalhos, rodapés, a interface inteira.
       </div>
```

A função é essa:

```
function carregar(){
            preload = document.getElementById("preload").style.display = 'none';
            div = document.getElementById("conteudo").style.display = 'block';
        }
```

Só que as coisas acontecem muito rápidas e o efeito não fica legal. Eu gostaria o gif sumisse com "fade" de 0.5s e o conteudo aparecesse com outro fade da mesma forma. Eu sei que isso é JQuery, só não sei fazer esse efeito.

Comment: Como estás a criar o conteúdo do site? É HTML estático? que espaço ocupa esse `loading.gif`? a tela toda como uma camada por cima do site?

Comment: É HTML estático, e esse `loading.gif` é centralizado no meio da tela, mas é só 200x200 px.

Comment: Se usar jQuery é muito fácil pois está tudo pronto, basta usar `$('#conteudo').show("slow")`, podes ver mais exemplos aqui: http://api.jquery.com/show/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podes criar uma função à mão para fazer fade...

Podia ser algo assim:

```js
function fade(el, tipo) {
    for (var i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
        setTimeout(function(nr) {
            var val = tipo == 'out' ? (100 - nr) / 100 : nr / 100;
            el.style.opacity = val;
            if (tipo == 'out' && nr == 100) el.style.display = 'none';
            else if (tipo == 'in' && nr == 0) el.style.display = 'block';
        }, 10 * i, i);
    }
}

function carregar() {
    fade(document.getElementById("preload"), 'out');
 fade(document.getElementById("conteudo"), 'in');
}
setTimeout(carregar, 500);
```

```css
div {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="preload">Preload</div>
<div id="conteudo" style="display: none;">Conteudo</div>
```

ou fazer isso com classes CSS e `transition: opacity 0.5s;`, porém a mudança de `display: block;` para `display: none;` tem de ser feita por JavaScript.